# ElasticSearch - Sum of Types in Nest Query

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, aggregate, nest

I'm using Nest to do an "_all" query on an ElasticSearchIndex.  I'm specifying three types:

```
                s.Types(typeof(TypeA), typeof(TypeB), typeof(TypeC));
                s.Query(q => q.QueryString(qs => qs
                   .DefaultField("_all")
                   .Query(criteria.SearchText)));
```

I'm trying to use Aggregations to get the totals found for each type.  I've tried using the Nest code like this:

```
s.Aggregations(a => a.Sum("typeA", b => b.Field("Type")));
```

But it has not worked.  Does anyone know how to accomplish this with Nest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sum aggregation is actually more for summing the values of field contents within your document. In your case since you just want a count of the documents, I would suggest you use a terms aggregation on the **_type** field. So use the following should get what you are looking for.

```
 s.Aggregations(a => a.Terms("types", b=>b.Field("_type")));
```

Hope this helps...